# Azure Container App increasing performance

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, jmeter, azure-front-door

I had .NET Core web app deployed to Azure Web App Service(Windows). It contains subfolder where I had 4 different project. Right now I shifted our app to Docker stuff. We have 4 different web app (based on container and using Linux) and Azure Front Door handling each request.

After launching my app I run some performance test using JMeter and noticed that my performance was decreased in 4 times! For instance the same request in old app takes 300ms but in new app it takes 1.2s.

I thought it could be due to Azure Front Door, but I made the same performance test direct to web service instead Front Door and got the same result.

Both environments have the same pricing plan. Why could I have that huge latency? How could I fix that use? Could Docker cause that issue due to non-optimal layers or something like this?